# How to bind XML attributes and all of their ancestors with xpath and lxml?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I have a XML file similar to the sample below. I was tasked to query that file with xpaths and lxml, and to store them in a database via Python and Django.

```
<foo n='foo56'>
  <moo n='moo254'>
    <too n='too24' =>
      <bar n='bar3'>
    <mar n='mar1'
         x = '1;2;3;4;5;6'
         y = '7;8;9;10;11;12'
         z = '13;14;15;16'
        />
    <mar n='mar2'
         x = '3;2;8;4;9;6'
         y = '7;8;7;14;13;12'
         z = '5;11;16;10'
        />
      </bar>    
      <bar n='bar56'>
    <mar n='mar1'
         x = '1;2;3;4;5;6'
         y = '7;8;9;10;11;12'
         z = '13;14;15;16'
        />
    <mar n='mar2'
         x = '3;2;8;4;9;6'
         y = '7;8;7;14;13;12'
         z = '5;11;16;10'
        />
      </bar>    
      <bar n='barX'>
    <mar n='mar1'
         x = values x
         y = values y
         z = values z
        />
    <mar n='mar2'
         x = values x
         y = values y
         z = values z
        />  
      </bar>    
     </too>
   </moo>
</foo>
```

I need to retrieve the x, y, and z values, and place these in a Container python 
object, these Containers will be linked by foreign key to another python object
we'll call a Node.

On top of retrieving these data, I'll need to associate to each Node several Containers object in which I'll have to put the 'n' value of a XML element, associated with the tag of that XML element.

Here is a simplification of my data model :

Node : 
name : link
id : link_id

Container :
key : x
value : '1;2;3;4;5;6'
node : link_id

Container :
key : y
value : values y
node : link_id

Container :
key : z
value : values z
node : link_id

Container :
key : mar
value : mar1
node : link_id

Container :
key : bar
value : bar3
node : link_id

I must use one xpath to retrieve the data of each container, I can't use more
or can't use less.

I already have a parser which can handle XML files, and parse them based on
pre-writen Xpaths (but that can't register these in my database yet, since data are not sorted at all)

My problem remains, I don't know how to get the relationship between the elements and attributes after applying the xpath. Thus, I can't save in my database any data I retrieve with the xpath, otherwise I'll have useless x, y and z values without knowing to what these values refer.

To sum up :

**Is there a way to know that x, y, and z belongs to mar1, which
belongs to bar3 ?**

**Is it something that can be done in Python, with lxml and xpath to retrieve some data or all data and associate these just like in my example with Node and Containers ?**

Thanks for reading.

EDIT 24/06/2016 :

Here is a sample of my XML file, and an expected output :

```
   <treatment name="testing">      
     <process  name="running_test">       
      <measure name="memory_user_1">
       <values name="Amount" 
                  x="6" 
                  y=".25"  
                  z="3.00" 
        /> 
      </measure> 
      <measure name="memory_user_2"> 
       <values name="Amount" 
                  x="3" 
                  y=".14" 
                  z="1.68" 
        /> 
      </measure> 
     </process>
   </treatment>
```

After parsing such XML I'd like to retrieve something like :

```
[
  {treatment : 'testing', process : 'running_test', measure : 'memory_user_1' , values : 'amount', x : '6', y : '.25', z : '3.00'},
  {treatment : 'testing', process : 'running_test', measure : 'memory_user_2' , values : 'amount', x : '3', y : '.14', z : '1.68'}
]
```

Comment: What is Container supposed to represent and why a single xpath?

Comment: It is supposed to be an instance of a django class to store data inside my database. About the second point perhaps I explained it the wrong way, I need one xpath per type of value, thus one xpath to retrieve one or all x data, one xpath to retrieve one or all y data and so on. That's part of my job, my spec doesn't allow me to retrieve multiple data with the same xpath.

Comment: Can you add an example of output using a structure like a python dict?

Comment: Okay ! So I'd like in the end to be able to build N objects, looking like { x : xvalue, y : yvalue, z : zvalue, mar : 'mar1', bar : 'bar3' }. By doing this, I'm looking forward to be able to know later from which bar, mar, too foo, moo etc... my data came from, to filter these based on attributes from the said XML Element.

Comment: I meant add it to your question, also adding an actual small, valid and runnable xml sample with the expected output is said dict would make your intent a lot more clear.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I edited my first post with an output, and something more functionnal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, to solve my problem I used a special solution using a global xpath and a group of relativ xpaths.

The global xpath returns a list of terminal elements, the one containing the values I want :

```
global_xpath = '/foo/moo/too/bar/mar'
```

I also have a list of relativ xpaths looking like :

```
local_xpath = './ancestor::bar'
```

By iterating over the result of the first xpath, and then iterating over the list of relativ xpaths to get all the ancestors of my element, and also its attributes, I can achieve what I needed.

It's working like that :

```
    xpath_list = ['./ancestor::list','./ancestor::of', './ancestor::xpaths']
    global_xpath = '/xpath/to/some/elements'
    f_path = '/some/path/to/file/'

    pfile = etree.parse(f_path)

    global_x = pfile.xpath(global_xpath)

    for path in global_x:

        #creates object Node

        for r_path in xpath_list

            local_x = path.xpath(r_path)

            #creates Containers objects

            #links Containers to the Node
```